# How to change mysql row result to column

Tags: php, mysql, select, join

I have a sql query like this:

```
SELECT mahasiswa.nim, mahasiswa.nama, nilai_pretest.nilai_pretest, nilai_session.nilai_session FROM nilai_session 
INNER JOIN materi ON materi.id_materi=nilai_session.id_materi
INNER JOIN nilai_pretest ON nilai_pretest.id_nilai_pretest=nilai_session.id_nilai_pretest
INNER JOIN pengambilan ON pengambilan.id_pengambilan=nilai_pretest.id_pengambilan 
INNER JOIN mahasiswa ON mahasiswa.nim= pengambilan.nim
INNER JOIN pengampu ON pengampu.id_pengampu= pengambilan.id_pengampu 
WHERE pengampu.id_pengampu=4
```

the result is:

```
+-----------+-------+---------------+---------------+ 
| nim        | nama  | nilai_pretest | nilai_session | 
+------------+-------+---------------+---------------+ 
| 1215051173 | nama1 | 70            | 100           |
| 1215051173 | nama1 | 70            | 35            |
| ...        | ....  |               |               |
+------------+-------+---------------+---------------+
```

but I want the result like this:

```
+-----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------+
| nim        | nama  | nilai_pretest | materi1 | materi2 | materi... |
+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------+
| 1215051173 | nama1 | 70            | 100     | 35      | ...       |
| ...        | ....  | ...           | ...     | ...     | ...       |
+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-----------+
```

How do I handle this? I have tried many ways, but still not working.

================================================

my structure table is:

** nilai_session table

```
+-----------------+---------------+------------------+-----------+
| id_nilai_session | nilai_session | id_nilai_pretest | id_materi |
+------------------+---------------+------------------+-----------+
| 8                | 100           | 5                | ...       |
| 9                | 35            | 5                | ...       |
| ...              | ....          | ...              | ...       |
+------------------+---------------+------------------+-----------+
```

** materi table

```
+-----------+-------------+-----+
| id_materi | judul_materi | ... |
+-----------+--------------+-----+
| 5         | 6            | ... |
| ...       | ....         | ... |
+-----------+--------------+-----+
```

** nilai_pretest table

```
+-----------------+--------------+---------------+ 
| id_nilai_pretest | id_pengambil | nilai_pretest |
+------------------+--------------+---------------+
| 5                | 6            | 70            |
| ...              | ....         | ...           |
+------------------+--------------+---------------+
```

** pengambilan table

```
+---------------+-------------+------------+
| id_pengambilan | id_pengampu | nim        |
+----------------+-------------+------------+
| 6              | 4           | 1215051173 |
| ...            | ....        | ...        |
+----------------+-------------+------------+
```

** mahasiswa table

```
+-----------+-------+
| nim        | nama  |
+------------+-------+
| 1215051173 | nama1 |
| 1215051112 | nama2 |
| ...        | ....  |
+------------+-------+
```

** pengampu table

```
+------------+---------------+------+
| id_pengampu | id_matakuliah | ...  |
+-------------+---------------+------+
| 4           | TIK1225       | ...  |
| 5           | TIK1204       | ...  |
| ...         | ....          | ...  |
+-------------+---------------+------+
```

thanks for attention.

Comment: It's not clear from your question, how do you separate  values across colomns materi1, materi2. Is it based on the nilai_pretest value? How?

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: @Lamar yes, based on nilai_pretest.

Comment: How? Is it value range, or unique values?

Comment: that is value range.

Comment: So you need to show us how what are the ranges, because this can only work on hard coded values or ranges.

Comment: sorry, my bad. actually the materi1, materi2, ... materi(n) based on nilai_session.

Comment: unless your `n` in that `materi(n)` is fixed, it's not possible in mysql afaik. some database systems have some pivoting functions. you probably have to solve this problem in php (since you provided it as a tag).